# Not letting me make a new embedded page to the index

Tags: html

**Question and Explanation:** So I was working on having pages embedded in the index html page and had the Home and Calendar pages work. However the Live Help does not seem to work. Everything else is good except the Live Help button does not seem to do anything. How can I fix this and turn the Live Help button into a workable page embedded into the index html page.

**Here is the code (index.html + script.js):**

```js
/*
••••••••••••••••••••••••

Powered by Type & Grids™
www.typeandgrids.com

••••••••••••••••••••••••
*/

jQuery.easing.def = "easeOutQuad";

$(document).ready(function()
{
 
 // Make enlarge buttons inactive if no onClick event
 $(".enlargeButton").each(function() {
        if ( $(this).attr("onClick") == undefined )  {
            $(this).addClass("projectNavInactive");
        };
    });
 
 // For fluid video embedding
 $(".video").fitVids();
 
 // Hide project info
 $(".projectInfo").css("display", "none");
 // Don't hide video info
 $(".videoInfo").css("display", "inline");
 
 // Move projects to second column
 $(".project:odd").appendTo("#col2");
  
 // Project thumbnail hover
 $(".projectThumbnail").on("mouseenter", function(e)
 {
  $(this).children(".projectThumbnailHover").fadeIn(300);
  
  $(this).children(".projectThumbnailHover").find("h4").css("display", "block");
  $(this).children(".projectThumbnailHover").find("h4").css("opacity", "0");
  $(this).children(".projectThumbnailHover").find("h4").delay(200).animate({left: '30', opacity: 1}, 200);
  
  $(this).children(".projectThumbnailHover").find("h5").css("display", "block");
  $(this).children(".projectThumbnailHover").find("h5").css("opacity", "0");
  $(this).children(".projectThumbnailHover").find("h5").delay(350).animate({left: '30', opacity: 1}, 200);
 })
 
 $(".projectThumbnail").on("mouseleave", function(e)
 {
  $(this).children(".projectThumbnailHover").fadeOut(200);
  $(this).children(".projectThumbnailHover").find("h4").animate({left: '0', opacity: 0}, 0);
  $(this).children(".projectThumbnailHover").find("h5").animate({left: '0', opacity: 0}, 0);
 })
 
 // Hide hover effect on touch devices
 if (Modernizr.touch) {
  $(".projectThumbnailHover").css("display", "none");
  $(".projectThumbnailHover").css("visibility", "hidden");
  $(".projectThumbnail").unbind("mouseenter");
  $(".projectThumbnail").unbind("mouseleave"); 
 }
 
 // Page navigation
 var isWorkCurrentPage = true;
 var isAboutCurrentPage = false;
 
 $("#logoDetailView").click(function()
 {
  window.location = "../../index.html";
 });
 
 $("#workPage, #logo").click(function()
  {
   if(!isWorkCurrentPage)
   {
    isWorkCurrentPage = true;
    isAboutCurrentPage = false;
    $("#workPage").attr("class", "currentPage");
    $("#aboutPage").removeClass("currentPage");
    
    $("#about").fadeOut(500, function()
    {
     $("#work").fadeIn(500);
    });
   }
  });
 
 $("#aboutPage").click(function()
  {
   if(!isAboutCurrentPage)
   {
    isAboutCurrentPage = true;
    isWorkCurrentPage = false;
    $("#aboutPage").attr("class", "currentPage");
    $("#workPage").removeClass("currentPage");
    
    $("#work").fadeOut(500, function()
    {
     $("#about").fadeIn(500);
    });
   }
  });
 
 // Make Work page current page
 $("#workPage").attr("class", "currentPage");
 
 // Hide About page
 //$("#about").css("display", "none");
 $("#about").fadeOut(0);
 
 // For site fade site in
 $(".container").css("display", "none");
 
});

// Remove site preloader after site is loaded
$(window).load(function() {
 $('#sitePreloader').delay(200).fadeOut(500, function() {
  $(this).remove();
 });
 
 // Fade site in
 $(".container").delay(700).fadeIn(500);
});

// Portfolio slider setup
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 var sliderProps = {
  autoScaleSlider: true,
     autoScaleSliderWidth: 460,
     autoScaleSliderHeight: 284,
     captionShowEffects: '',
     controlNavEnabled: false,
     keyboardNavEnabled: true,
     directionNavEnabled: false,
     startSlideIndex: 0,
     imageScaleMode: 'fill' },
  openedProjectInfo,
  isAnimating = false,
  currOpenProject;

 function closeOpenedProject(el) {
  openedProjectInfo.slideUp(900);
  openedProjectInfo.parent().find('.portfolioSlider').fadeOut();
  openedProjectInfo = false;
  if(el && el.length) {
   el.css('visibility', 'visible');
  }
 }

 $(".projectThumbnail").click(function(e) {
  if(isAnimating) {
   return;
  }
  isAnimating = true;
  
  var firstImgLoaded = false,
   projectEl = $(this).parent('.project'),
   projectNav = projectEl.find('.projectNav'),
   
   //
   projectInfo = projectEl.find('.projectInfo'),
   //
   
   newOpenProjectInfo = projectEl.find(".projectInfo"),
   currEl = $(this).find(".thumbnailImage");
    
  if( !projectEl.data('slider-inited') ) {
   var portfolioSliderData = projectEl.find('.portfolioSliderData'),
    imgPreloaderOverlay;
  
   if(portfolioSliderData.length > 0) {
    imgPreloaderOverlay = $('<div class="first-img-preloader"><div class="preloader-graphics"></d</div>');
    projectEl.append(imgPreloaderOverlay);

    portfolioSliderData
     .addClass('portfolioSlidesContainer')
     .wrap($('<div class="portfolioSlider"></div>'))
     .find('li').addClass('portfolioSlide');
   
    var sliderEl = projectEl.find('.portfolioSlider');
    currEl.clone().addClass('portfolioImage myImage').appendTo(sliderEl.find('li').eq(0).removeAttr('data-src'));
    var imgLoadCounter = 0;
    
    var sliderInstance = sliderEl.portfolioSlider(sliderProps).data('portfolioSlider');
    var numSlides = sliderInstance.numSlides;
    
    // Fixes bug when resizing window on About page
    $("#logo, #workPage").click(function() {
     function bugFix() {
      sliderInstance.updateSliderSize();
      $(".projectThumbnailHover").fadeOut(800);
     }
     setTimeout(bugFix, 710);
    });
    
    //var currItemCounter = projectNav.find('.projectNavCounter'),
    var currItemCounter = projectInfo.find('.projectNavCounter'),
     arrowNext = projectNav.find('.projectNavButtons .next'),
     arrowPrev = projectNav.find('.projectNavButtons .prev'),
     arrowPrevBlocked = false,
     arrowNextBlocked = false;

    function updateNextPrevButtons() {
     if(sliderInstance.currentSlideId <= 0) {
      arrowPrev.addClass('projectNavInactive');
      arrowPrevBlocked = true;
     } else {
      arrowPrev.removeClass('projectNavInactive');
      arrowPrevBlocked = false;
     }

     if(sliderInstance.currentSlideId >= numSlides - 1) {
      arrowNext.addClass('projectNavInactive');
      arrowNextBlocked = true;
     } else {
      arrowNext.removeClass('projectNavInactive');
      arrowNextBlocked = false;
     }
    }

    sliderInstance.settings.beforeSlideChange = function() {
     currItemCounter.text( (sliderInstance.currentSlideId + 1) + ' of ' + numSlides );
     updateNextPrevButtons();
    };
    
    arrowNext.click(function() {
     if(!arrowNextBlocked) {
      sliderInstance.next();
     }
    });
    arrowPrev.click(function() {
     if(!arrowPrevBlocked) {
      sliderInstance.prev();
     }
    });

    sliderInstance.settings.beforeSlideChange.call();
    updateNextPrevButtons();
    projectEl.data('slider-inited', true);
    
    imgPreloaderOverlay.css({
     width: currEl.width(),
     height: currEl.height()
    }).fadeIn();

    sliderInstance.settings.imgLoadComplete = function() {
     imgLoadCounter++;

     if(imgLoadCounter >= 2) {
      sliderInstance.settings.imgLoadComplete = false;
      setTimeout(function() {
       //sliderInstance.updateSliderSize()
       sliderInstance.goTo(1);
       isAnimating = false;
       currEl.css('visibility', 'hidden');
       imgPreloaderOverlay.stop().fadeOut();
      }, 400);
     }
     
    };

   } else {
    if(projectNav.length > 0) {
     var currItemCounter = projectInfo.find('.projectNavCounter'),
     arrowNext = projectNav.find('.projectNavButtons .next'),
     arrowPrev = projectNav.find('.projectNavButtons .prev'),
     arrowPrevBlocked = false,
     arrowNextBlocked = false;
     arrowNext.addClass('projectNavInactive');
     arrowPrev.addClass('projectNavInactive');
    }
    projectEl.data('slider-inited', true);
    isAnimating = false;
   }
  } else {
   var sliderEl = projectEl.find('.portfolioSlider');
   if(sliderEl.length > 0) {
    sliderEl.data('portfolioSlider').goToSilent(0);
    imgPreloaderOverlay = projectEl.find('.first-img-preloader');
    imgPreloaderOverlay.css({
     width: currEl.width(),
     height: currEl.height()
    }).fadeIn();

    setTimeout(function() {
     sliderEl.show();
     
     setTimeout(function() {
      currEl.css({'visibility': 'hidden'});
      imgPreloaderOverlay.stop().fadeOut();
      sliderEl.data('portfolioSlider').isAnimating = false;
      sliderEl.data('portfolioSlider').goTo(1);
      isAnimating = false;
     }, 400);
     
    }, 450);
    
   } else {
    isAnimating = false;
   }
   
  }

  if(openedProjectInfo) {
   if(newOpenProjectInfo.is(openedProjectInfo)) {
    closeOpenedProject(currOpenProject.find(".thumbnailImage"));
    currOpenProject.find(".projectThumbnailHover").fadeOut(800, function(){currOpenProject.find(".projectThumbnailHover").css("visibility", "visible")});
    return false;
   } else {
    closeOpenedProject(currOpenProject.find(".thumbnailImage"));
    currOpenProject.find(".projectThumbnailHover").fadeOut(800, function(){currOpenProject.find(".projectThumbnailHover").css("visibility", "visible")});
   }
  }
  currOpenProject =projectEl;
  openedProjectInfo = newOpenProjectInfo.stop().delay(200).slideDown(900).data('project-open', true);
  currOpenProject.find(".projectThumbnailHover").fadeOut(200, function(){currOpenProject.find(".projectThumbnailHover").css("visibility", "hidden")});
 });
 
 $(".closeButton, #aboutPage, #logo").click(function() {
  
  // Add a delay to fix weird issue with resizing About page
  function closeSlider() {
   closeOpenedProject(currOpenProject.find(".thumbnailImage"));
   currOpenProject.find(".projectThumbnailHover").css("visibility", "visible");
  }
  //setTimeout(closeSlider, 400);
  setTimeout(closeSlider, 1);
  
 });
 
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie6" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="ie ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<!--
••••••••••••••••••••••••

Powered by Type & Grids™
www.typeandgrids.com

••••••••••••••••••••••••
-->

<title>West Torrance High School's AP Physics</title>
<meta name="description" content="The website of WHS Physics">
<meta name="author" content="West Torrance High School's AP Physics">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

<!-- CSS
================================================================================================= -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/type_05.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/color_06.css">

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!-- Favicons
================================================================================================= -->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicons/favicon.ico">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/favicons/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="images/favicons/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="images/favicons/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">

<!-- JS
================================================================================================= -->
<script src="js/libs/modernizr.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/jquery.easing.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/jquery.fitvids.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<!-- Write preloader to page - this allows the site to load for users with JS disabled -->
<script type="text/javascript">
 document.write("<div id='sitePreloader'><div id='preloaderImage'><img src='images/site_preloader.gif' alt='Preloader' /></div></div>");
</script>

<div class="container">
 
 <!-- Header begins ========================================================================== -->
 <header class="sixteen columns">
  <div id="logo">
   <h1>West Torrance High School's AP Physics</h1>
   <h2>2016-2017</h2>
   <!--
   <img src="images/logo.png" width="275" height="35" alt="Logo" />
   -->
  </div>
  <nav>
   <ul>
    <li><button id="workPage">Home</button></li>
    <li><button id="aboutPage">Calendar</button></li>
    <li><button id="chickenPage">Live Help</button></li>
    <!--<li><a href="http://wordpress.org" target="_blank">Blog</a></li>-->
   </ul>
  </nav>
  <hr />
 </header>
 
 <div id="work">
 
  <div id="overview" class="sixteen columns">
   <h3>? days till the AP TEST!</h3>
   <hr />
  </div>
   
   <h3>Announcements</h3>
   
   <p> Hello world. </p>
 
 </div>

 <div id="about">
  
  <!-- Column 1 begins ==================================================================== -->
  <div class="eight columns">
   
   <iframe src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?height=600&amp;wkst=1&amp;bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&amp;ctz=America%2FLos_Angeles" style="border-width:0" width="940" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>   
   
  </div>
  <!-- Column 2 ends ====================================================================== -->
    
 </div>
 
 <div id="chicken">
 
 
 </div>

 
 
 <!-- About page ends ======================================================================== -->
 
 <!-- Footer begins ========================================================================== -->
 <footer class="sixteen columns">
  <hr />
  <ul id="footerLinks">
   <li>&copy; 2016 Julian Rachman. All rights reserved.</li>
   <li><a href="mailto:jmrachman@gmail.com">jmrachman@gmail.com</a></li>
  </ul>
 </footer>
 <!-- Footer ends ============================================================================ -->
  
</div><!-- container -->
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you. (P.S., running the code from stackoverflow is an incorrect rendition of my code)

Comment: where is your script.js ?

Comment: @gayathri Thank you. It has been added.

Comment: i havent see any onlcik for the liveHelp button from your script.js